# Meteor read file sync issue

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

I have issue with meteor app deployed with yamup in Ubuntu.

```
const tmpFilePath = Meteor.settings['DOWNLOADS_PATH'] + '/tmp/' + fileName;
    wkhtmltopdf(html, { pageSize: 'A4', encoding: 'utf-8' })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFilePath))
        .on('error', (err) => {
            future.return({ err, buffer: null });
        }).on('close', () => {
            # here occur issue #
            const buffer = fs.readFileSync(tmpFilePath);
            fs.unlinkSync(tmpFilePath);
            future.return({ err: null, buffer });
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwcwq.png)
tmp file is generated on tmp directory with root permission, but can not read and write sync.
What is solutions?

Comment: How did you deploy your Meteor application? Also, how do you write to the tmp directory?

Comment: How do you know that it's written with root permission?

Comment: I deployed with yamup npm modules, and tmp directory is made by settings.json.
{
"DOWNLOADS_PATH": "/var/www/web-data/downloads",
"DOWNLOADS_HOST": "http://mydomain:8080",
"LOGS_PATH": "/var/www/web-data/logs",
"public": { }
}

Comment: Hello Jankapunkt.
I checked tmp directory is made with root permission.
I added additional image.